# Z Homing issue after Marlin 2.1.2 upgrade on Ender 3 with BTT SKR mini V2.0 and BLTouch

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin

So my Ender 3 with a BLTouch running on a BIGTREETECH SKR MINI V2.0 mainboard has been working just fine on Marlin 2.0.8 for a year or so and I decided I would update it to Marlin 2.1.2.

I downloaded the 2.1.2 pre-configured firmware from BIGTREETECH's Github open it in VS Code and do the usual:

1. Make sure `Z_MIN_PROBE_USES_Z_MIN_ENDSTOP_PIN` is uncommented.
2. Uncomment `#define BLTouch`.
3. Set probe offsets
4. Uncomment `ENABLE_LEVELING_FADE_HEIGHT`
5. Uncomment `Z_SAFE_HOMING`
6. Comment `MESH_LEVELING` and uncomment `BILINEAR_LEVELING` for auto bed leveling
7. Comment out `MIN_SOFTWARE_ENDSTOP_Z`
8. Uncomment `BLTOUCH_DELAY` and `BLTOUCH_FORCE_SW_MODE`

I compiled, placed firmware.bin on the SD card, flashed it and everything seemed fine until I tried to home my Z-axis.

The probe sticks out and retreats twice the light stays blue, the gantry doesn't move at all and the LCD reads "STOPPED". I have no idea why this is happening any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you every figure out the issue? I have an Ender 3 Pro with CRTouch, board 4.2.2 and getting exactly what you described.